# Side scroller game, classes & flow

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, structure

I am trying to develop a sidescroller game in as3. Most of my confusion is coming from my lack of knowledge on the best way to strucutre the classes that control the games flow.

For example, what would be the best way to change the game state from the main menu, to the in game state, WITH VISUAL TRANSITION INCLUDED?

The way I'm thinking of doing it now is adding event listeners to buttons, which remove the main menu MC and add a transition MC. Then I add an event listener to the transition MC to watch for the frame label "end of transition". This removes the transition MC and adds the GameContainer MC.

Is this efficient? Are there other ways to do it that are easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle states in a flash videogame is to create states as MovieClip subclasses.  You create then a StateManager with the ability to move from one state to another handling any transition in between.  As for transitions between the menu and the in game state, I don't know how you are doing it but you should consider loading level specific assets during transition (using a progress bar or an animation) and moving to in game when it finishes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know this wasn't in the original question, but how would you loads specific assets from the library? I thought everything loads at the same time since I have a preloader at the start of the game.

Comment: Games tend to have a large amount of assets, specially if they consist of many levels.  So you don't load everything at the beginning but instead load things as you need them.  This can be done with a ResourceManager that knows exactly what to load for each state or level of your game.  When I implement resource managers what I do is that I first write a xml with a list of things that need to be loaded into the level (paths) and then use a Loader to load them into the game.  You can also use the xml to specify what the resources are and where and how to use them in your game.

Comment: this answer is fine for very small projects/testing but not much else. Lebowski, this tutorial will walk you through a full game.http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/